# Unable to POST data in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have developed a sample applications using Python Django Rest framework to implement basic CRUD operations. In this application , I am using **MySQL** database. I have created database named **roytuts** and a table named as **user**. In this **user** table i have declared various fields such as : **id,name,email,phone,address** .

**PROBLEM :** The problem is I have declared id as **AUTO INCREMENT**. When i post data without providing **id** it gives error(although it should not give as **id** is auto increment). I have to manually provide **id** to POST data.

**Below are the screen shots**
[image: Error if no id is provided]

[image: no error if id is provided manually]

**Repository Github Link** : https://github.com/mohitkrsharma/RestAPI.git

**Any solution please ?**

Comment: `id` exists by default and is auto-increment. Try removing `id` from your model and see if it works.

Comment: Ali Tou: Do i have to makemigrations again in that case ?

Comment: @MohitKumarSharma yes you have to makemigrations && migrate again. You don't have to declare id field on your models. It already exists like Ali Tou said.